# Variavel dentro de ponteiro de uma classe

Tags: c++, classes

Eu tenho vários arquivos de cabeçalho com funções de gerenciamento de GUI que eu fiz para criar janelas, parecido com aquelas bibliotecas como GTK, QT e outros, e estou as transformando em biblioteca, mas estou com um problema que vai ser um pouco complicado de explicar.

Eu tenho uma classe chamada TD_Control que representa um controle como botão, `textBox` e outros, dentro dela tem um membro chamado id que é um numero inteiro que representa a id do objeto no `loop` de mensagens, basicamente até aqui minha classe é assim:

```
class TD_Control
{
public:
    int id;
    ... // Esta classe é muito grande, por isso abreviei
}
```

E tenho uma função chamada TD_GetID() que gera uma nova id diferente de todas geradas e basicamente ele soma o valor de uma variável retorna um novo valor, assim:

```
// Esta variavel é global
int TD_ID_COUNTER = 5000;

int TD_GetID()
{
    TD_ID_COUNTER++;
    return TD_ID_COUNTER - 1;
}
```

E para criar um controle existe uma função para criar cada tipo de controle como essa que cria um `TextBox`:

```
TD_Control* TD_CreateControlTextBox()
{
    TD_Control* ec = new TD_Control();
    int nid = TD_GetID();
    ...// Esta classe é muito grande, por isso abreviei
    return ec;
}
```

Todas essas funções estão dentro de uma static library, eu compilei e deu tudo certo, criei janelas, controles e outros, mas ao criar varios controles e usar eventos tive um problema, veja este exemplo:

```
// Tb1
TD_Control* TextBox1;
TextBox1 = TD_CreateControlTextBox();
// Tb2
TD_Control* TextBox2;
TextBox2 = TD_CreateControlTextBox();
```

Ao criar estes controles, cada um deveria ter uma id diferente, mas todos ficam com a mesma id sendo todas igual a 5002. Será que é porque a o objeto da classe é um ponteiro e ao usar objeto de ponteiro ele tem alguma característica diferente? Ou tem algo de errado no meu código?

Infelizmente não é possível colocar o código inteiro pois é muito grande, só o código fonte principal tem 2156 linhas.

Comment: Vc deveria mudar seu codigo para que podesse ser criado assim: TextBox* textBox1 = new TextBox();

Comment: Está compilando tudo em uma única biblioteca ou existem várias bibliotecas parciais? Isso faz diferença ao lidar com variáveis estáticas, pois pode existir mais de uma "cópia", uma em cada biblioteca.

Comment: O seu código para `TD_GetID()` é equivalente à: `int TD_GetID() { return TD_ID_COUNTER++; }`. Você tá usando uma linha a mais, e uma subtração a mais atoa.

Comment: E provavelmente TD_ID_COUNTER deveria ser uma variável estática da função e não global. Além de provavelmente merecer outro nome e "casing".

Comment: Na função "TD_Control* TD_CreateControlTextBox()" você está criando o novo id assim "int nid = TD_GetID();", mas pelo menos neste trecho de código você **não** está inicializando o membro "id" da classe TD_CreateControlTextBox. Note que sua função factory **não** é uma instância da classe que ela está criando, portanto a variável "id" dentro da factory é uma variável local da factory, não um membro da instância sendo criada.

Comment: Sugestão: C++ tem namespaces, então você pode criar um namespace "TD", colocar tudo dentro e obter as mesmas vantagens que você está obtendo com o prefixo "TD", mas sem poluir os códigos clientes da sua biblioteca.

Answer (score 1):

Com as informações que você deu, eu só posso tentar supor o motivo. Eu posso tentar melhorar minha resposta se você esclarecer as duas questões abaixo:

1. Sua variável global declarada desse jeito: `int TD_ID_COUNTER = 5000;` está em um cabeçalho ou num arquivo .cpp?
2. Você cria dois `TextBox` assim, em sequencia, como nesse seu exemplo aí, ou você os cria em arquivos separados?

Se as respostas forem: "1) num cabeçalho", e "2) em arquivos diferentes", eu suspeito que você cria várias instâncias diferentes da variável `TD_ID_COUNTER` ao incluir o cabeçalho em arquivos .cpp diferentes. Se for esse o problema, a solução é colocar no cabeçalho somente:

```
extern int TD_ID_COUNTER;
```

e dentro de algum .cpp (e de somente um), a declaração da variável:

```
int TD_ID_COUNTER = 5000;
```

Comment: A variavel int 'TD_ID_COUNTER = 5000;' esta em um arquivo cpp do projeto da biblioteca, por ela ser apenas um contador interno eu não a adicionei o extern da variavel no arquivo de cabeçalho pois ela é usada somente dentro da biblioteca apenas gera novas ids para diferenciar cada objeto. A variável que gera IDs funciona perfeitamente, cada chamada da função 'int TD_GetID()' gera um novo numero, porem o membro 'int id;' da classe 'class TD_Control' parece apontar para o TD_ID_COUNTER de forma que ao criar outros objetos, os objetos anteriores ficam com a mesma id, mas o membro id não é ponteiro

Comment: Os TextBox são criados em sequencia, mas a cada vez que cria um textBox é chamada a função 'TD_CreateControlTextBox' que cria a classe com uma nova id gerada pelo retorno da função 'TD_GetID()'.

Comment: Entendi, então o problema não deve ser da variável `TD_ID_COUNTER` ser instanciada repetidamente. A propósito, como ela é usada só internamente ao arquivo, você deveria declará-la como `static int TD_ID_COUNTER = 5000;`. Agora eu acho que o único jeito de descobrir o problema é vendo o corpo completo da sua função `TD_CreateControlTextBox()`. Você pode me garantir que os 2 ponteiros retornados são diferentes? (`std::cout << TextBox1 != TextBox2 << std::endl;`)